# ¿Como crear salto de pagina y agregar class de css a texto en ITextSharp? C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

Tengo el siguiente código que genera un documento pdf con texto en html:

```
byte[] bPDF = null;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
string pHTML="<div class=\"estilos\">Esto es un ejemplo</div>";
pHTML="<div style=\"page-break-after: always\""</div>;
pHTML=pHTML+"fin";
TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(pHTML);
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);
PdfWriter oPdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(doc);
doc.Open();
htmlWorker.StartDocument();
htmlWorker.Parse(txtReader);
htmlWorker.EndDocument();
htmlWorker.Close();
doc.Close();
bPDF = ms.ToArray();
```

Mi pregunta como puedo agregar una clase de css al texto pHTML. Y como agregar salto de pagina al documento pdf, ya que he probado con page-break-after: always, pero no me resulta.

Comment: que libreria usas para convertir el html en pdf ? porque deberias ver la documentacion de esta para agregar estilos, quizas no puedas usar un .css se parado pero si definir el `<style></style>`

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, uso ITextSharp, está en la pregunta.

Comment: creo que usas una libreria incorrecta, porque esta ya esta deprecada, tienes que usar iText7 https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Si analizamos

[iText 7: Converting HTML to PDF with pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/intro)

veras que comenta

> The HTMLWorker class was deprecated many years ago

Es por eso que primero deberias cambiar la libreria y usar `iText7`

[iText7 nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/)

Entonces usaras la funcionalidad de `pdfHTML`

En el [Chapter 2: Defining styles with CSS](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-2-defining-styles-css) esta el titulo "External CSS"

La idea es que uses

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf()
```